# Setting up wazuh server at different location in multi-tenant environment

Tags: elasticsearch, multi-tenant, wazuh

Currently I am facing a challenge on the use-case that says:

`Setup the multi-tenant environment with Wazuh, the Kibana on cloud server for remote access to service provider teams but indexer and server should be stored at client location.`

Here the challenge is that the storage of logs should be kept at client location and only UI should be managed by Service provider.

Objective is to save storage on our side i.e., cloud machines instead all storage to be kept on client location

1. Is it possible that server can be kept together with Kibana on same cloud machine, but in this case the log storage should still be at client's location
2. Is it possible that both indexer and server are at client's location and configuration/lo search can be managed by single Kibana UI?

What are the possible outcomes to achieve this?